# Unable to run MVC 4 Razor C# solution with test

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

My solution is in `MVC 4` Razor C# with Test module. When I press F5  it just runs `MySolution.Test` Module and gives me test results only.

Can anyone help me hoe do i run my solution.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear the test project got set as the start-up project for debugging.

Assuming you're in Visual Studio, right-click on the non-test project in the Solution Explorer and click "Set as StartUp Project" to fix this. Then you should be able to use Start Debugging (F5) as normal.

Comment: can u help me , I wanna add a static HTML page to the solution, so How do i add it ?

Comment: @Nils That would be a new question.